# Search a query in multiple MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, search

hey guys  i just want to search ( Select ) in multiple tables  ,  so i wrote bellow code :

```
SELECT s.title From table_stories s WHERE s.title = %$inputbox% 
    UNION
    SELECT e.title From table_pages e WHERE e.title = %$inputbox%
```

is it wrong to use UNION >?!

Comment: you miss quotation marks around `%$inputbox%`. i also hope you escape $inputbox properly

Comment: No problem with using UNION. One addition you may like to make is add an extra column to each query to identify which TABLE the server returns data from. e.g. 'Stories' as TableName to the first and 'Pages' as TableName to the second in your example

Answer (score 2):

In the case of what you're doing here, it's perfectly reasonable to use UNION. Is there any particular reason why you think it might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

UNION is fine there.

Answer (score 0):

That seems perfectly valid. As you are asking I assume it doesn't work as expected. Are you trying to do something else? If you want to order the result then enclose the queries in parantheses

```
(SELECT s.title AS t From table_stories s WHERE s.title = %$inputbox%)
UNION
(SELECT e.title AS t From table_pages e WHERE e.title = %$inputbox%)
ORDER BY t
```

Answer (score 0):

problem was not in using UNION  ,  just mistake in Where condition

```
SELECT s.title AS t From table_stories s WHERE s.title like '%$inputbox%'
```